# Asyncio create task not running function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Using asyncio I am trying to spawn a task to stop my main event loop from being blocked by my socket listener. However, the asyncio create task function is never ran. The code runs because the `print("Game Loop")` statement is ran, but the `client_socket()` function code never emits.

```py
    async def main_loop(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(self.client_socket())
        while True:
           print("Game Loop")

    async def client_socket(self):
        print("Client socket online")
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host="127.0.0.1", port="55555")
        writer.write("CONNECT".encode("utf-8"))
        while True:
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your statement that `print("Game Loop")` has run, let's assume you are running this or something equivalent:

```py
asyncio.run(main_loop())
```

The function `client_socket` is never able to run because it is never awaited. `main_loop` does not yield control of the event loop.

To ensure `client_socket` runs after the first output of `Game Loop`, you can `await` it:

```py
        while True:
           print("Game Loop")
           await loop
```

If, however, you do not want to await `client_socket` any other `await` expression will yield control of the event loop. For example:

```py
        while True:
           print("Game Loop")
           await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the response. You are correct in your first few lines that I am using asyncio.run(main_loop()). 

I have just tried your solution with awaiting the loop (task) which I want to run, however if I do this it will then block the main game loop because its waiting for the client_socket to finish, but they should be running concurrently. 

As for the second solution, I cannot asyncio.sleep inside of the game loop because then it will sleep for 1 second on every frame and it would not run properly.

Comment: The example using `await asyncio.sleep(1)` does not have to be literal, though it must include an `await`. When calling `asyncio.sleep`, you can use `float` values such as `await asyncio.sleep(0.001)` or even 0 with `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to ensure other tasks can run.  
  
From https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep:   "Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking the event loop for the full duration of the function call."

Comment: Be aware that asyncio does not run things concurrently. It utilizes cooperative multitasking to allow one thing to run while others are waiting for I/O to complete.